# Iphone NSUserDefaults Trouble?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, uislider, uiswitch

In my app, I have an options page. It has 3 things you can change: a switch for inverted controls(it is a shooter game), a volume slider for the effects level, and a volume slider for the music level. I need help with a couple things. I am new (3 weeks) to objective c, and I need help with storing NSUserDefaults. I kind of have the code for the volume sliders, but it is not working. I also have no clue as what to do about the switch. I need to check this data later during the game, too. Here is the code I have tried 
OPTIONS.m

```
-(IBAction)musicVolumeChanged {

    NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *musicVolume = musicVolumeSlider.value;
    //theAudio.volume = musicVolume;
    [userPreferences setObject:musicVolume forKey:@"musicVolume"];
}

-(IBAction)effectsVolumeChanged {

    NSUserDefaults *userPreferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *effectsVolume = effectsVolumeSlider.value;
    //theAudio.volume = effectsVolume;
    [userPreferences setObject:effectsVolume forKey:@"effectsVolume"];

}
```

And then to access the values during the game, I have:
Igunner.m

```
NSString *effects_Volume = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                             stringForKey:@"effectsVolume"];
theAudio.volume = effects_Volume;
[theAudio play];
```

And then for the music volume i have:

```
NSString *music_Volume = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                                             stringForKey:@"musicVolume"];
theAudio.volume = music_Volume;
[theAudio play];
```

I have one error in each sample code shown above. for assigning the values to NSUserDefaults, I get an error when I am assigning the slider value for the string. "Incompatable types in Initialization", and for retrieving the values I get errors "Incompatable type for argument 1 of setVolume."

Please tell me what I am doing wrong, and If you know, please help me out on the switch state being stored and retrieved.

Comment: are you sure theAudio.volume is a NSString? I seriously doubt it. But you don't tell us what theAudio is so I can't give you the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSString *effectsVolume = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",effectsVolumeSlider.value];
```

Remember `slider.value` returns `float` so it cannot be assigned to a string directly.
This will solve the issue regarding assigning the values to user defaults

Answer (score 0):

at here you should cast float to string;

```
NSString *musicVolume = musicVolumeSlider.value;
```

athere you should cast string to float

```
theAudio.volume = music_Volume;
```

OR use

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setFloat:musicVolume forKey:@"musicVolume"];
```

instand of string